# How to remove tags in textOutput - RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to R and I am actually developing a page where a directory (string characters like "xx/xx") is given in the server and I want to take back this directory to include it in the source of my ui app.

UI:

```
library(shiny)
file<-textOutput("paramfile")
source(file(file), local = TRUE, encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

SERVER :

```
filedir<-renderText({
  "entries/5429_param.R"
})

output$paramfile<-renderText({
  filedir()
})
```

I then have an error :

> "Warning in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :   cannot open
>   file '< div id="paramfile" class="shiny-text-output">< /div>':
>   Invalid argument
>   Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
>   cannot open the connection"

Do you know how can I remove those tags or if there is another function that can allow me to take a string in the server and to include it into a source.

Comment: I still need some help, does anyone know how to take a string from the server and include it into the ui without any HTML tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example of a ShinyApp:

```
# Example of UI with fluidPage
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("dir", label = "Enter a directory")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("dirPrint"),
      verbatimTextOutput("lsFiles")
    )
  )
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$dirPrint <- renderPrint({
    print(input$dir)
  })

  output$lsFiles <- renderPrint({
    fls <- list.files(input$dir)
    print(fls)
  })
}

# Complete app with UI and server components
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you enter the path of a directory in the textinput, the second renderPrint function is showing all files, that are found at that path.

I would suggest you go over the [Shiny-Tutorials](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/), as there seem to be some syntax-problems in your code and I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve.